# Make secure API requests from Phonegap/Cordova application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am developing a Phonegap application which requests data via API form my server. Now, of course, I want that only my app can request this data and not everyone else with the domain. So I did http basic auth.

Which means I now have a user and password that the app sends along with the API request. The user and password are in my javascript but since Phonegap is turning this into a native app the source code is not so easily accessable.

Not so easily...but:

> Since a Cordova application is built from HTML and JavaScript assets
>   that get packaged in a native container, you should not consider your
>   code to be secure. It is possible to reverse engineer a Cordova
>   application.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_security_index.md.html

Is there any way to make secure requests or is this just not possible with Phonegap?

Comment: if you are asking if there is a way to make it so only your app can make requests to your backend. no there is no way everything can be circumvented. thank being said there are ways to make it harder, using encryption and obfuscation your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an [hmac key-hashed function](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#HMAC) to create a key by passing the message, user's password token and the utc datetime. this key will be appended to every request header. now the service will do the same thing on its side and it should return the same key. This will ensure that the message has not been tampered with at any point.

Comment: i think he is asking a way to stop other apps from being able to call the api,  and this wont stop that, if they just sign in and get thier own auth stuff and just run that algorithm on thier app